# Tumblr Photoset not working

Tags: tumblr

The theme I've chosen has decided to reduce photosets to the first frame, instead of giving the full photoset. I want a consolidated photoset shown on my page, instead of the first, single. I have no idea how to do this. I've tried looking on here, using this:

```
{block:Photoset}
{block:Photos}
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" class="photoset-img" />
{/block:Photos}
{/block:Photoset}
```

It worked, sort of. All the photos of the set were there, but they were large and connected together. The images in the photoset are now stacked vertically atop one another instead of side by side and are taking up a lot of space.

Comment: What is your question about?

Answer (score 1):

The theme block / variable below will generate an iframe containing the images, laid out, as they were set on the dashboard.

```
{block:Photoset}
{Photoset-500}
{/block:Photoset}
```